# How to stop hackers try from trying to hack my database?

Tags: sql-server

Looking at the error log and running Profiler I found these errors:

```
2019-10-08 13:27:47.64 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2019-10-08 13:27:47.64 Logon       Login failed for user 'mssqla'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 123.125.125.248]

2019-10-08 13:27:46.32 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-10-08 13:27:46.32 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 123.125.125.248]

2019-10-08 13:28:57.13 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2019-10-08 13:28:57.13 Logon       Login failed for user 'usera'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 123.125.125.248]
```

The users `usera` and `mssqla` don't exist and never were and I checked the ip address location and it shows it's origin is from China.

**Profiler trace results:**
[image]

I search the process id in my ubuntu using the command
`sudo ps -A` and processes not exist.

Am I being paranoid or someone from China tries to hack my Database and how can I stop him?

Comment: When you expose SQL Server to the public internet, you will have [script kiddies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_kiddie) trying to hack in continuously. Is there a reason you want anyone in the world accessing your server over the internet? If not, consider appropriate firewall rules, VPN, etc.

Comment: @DanGuzman 
My website and my ms-sql server are  on the same server, I don't understand how my website can work without accessing sql-server.

Comment: Since they are on the same server, SQL Server doesn't need to listen on an external interface so you can use 127.0.0.1. Create a firewall rule to block external port 1433 traffic except from hosts you use for remote management.

Comment: @DanGuzman thx I will try that, do you have any idea how those hackers found out about my website?

Comment: Mostly likely just a scan of random IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be able to do auditing the activities and trace the activities within SQL Instance, for blocking part the better place is firewall, you may follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443305/6598234) to automate the firewall blocking entries at windows firewall level.

In addition to the blocking, some [security recommendations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244434/185080) that you can refer to:

Answer (score 0):

That your webserver needs access to the database server is out of question - but at the same time this should be only in your local subnet. If possible place the database on a second server - even a properly run virtual one inside vmware ws or similar will do - just limit the access to the database server to your local subnet.